# isPrototypeOf and __proto__ have different results

Tags: javascript, prototype

The following two expressions:

```
"abc".__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf("abc")           // false
```

The first expression proves that `Object.prototype` lies in the prototype chain of "abc". However, the second expression gets an opposite result.

I am very confused. Hope anyone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"abc"` is not an object. When you evaluate `"abc".__proto__`, a `String` wrapper object is implicitly constructed to retrieve the prototype of, and `Object.prototype` is in that wrapper object's prototype chain.

`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf("abc")` doesn't construct a wrapper object. It just looks at `"abc"`, sees that `"abc"` isn't an object and has no prototype chain, and returns false. You can see this in the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.isprototypeof) (version 6):

> When the isPrototypeOf method is called with argument V, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If Type(V) is not Object, return false.